# OpenFile Dialog how to select multiselect files but not folders?

Tags: c++, mfc

How using MFC class `CFileDialog` set flags to have possibility select several files, but prevent from selecting multiple folders?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by adding the flag **OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT** in the **CFileDialog** constructor.

Comment: but then i can select several folders